# Highcharts: Standard deviation bands VWAP indicator

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

We are using highcharts: 11.1.0 and implemented Volume Weighted Average Price (VWAP) indicator. We are able to plot normal VWAP indicator, But we want to implement the deviation bands along side the indicator series like below:

[image]

Can anyone please help us with any example on how we can implement.

Comment: Here is the list of available technical indicators directly from the Highcharts Stock API:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/technical-indicator-series. If you don't find the one you're looking for, you can create your own based on this guideline: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/custom-technical-indicators